Getting Error when building Spring application : Error parsing HTTP request header
I recently pulled this repo to learn and understand more on spring security.
Link- https://github.com/shaikhf04/spring-security-registration
However, I used IntelliJ to pull this repo and trying to build the application as is. When I am trying to build the application it's giving me error. I'm adding the entire log trace for you to give me input to help understand how do I tackle this problem.
Logs-
`
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-22\bin\java.exe" -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dspring.jmx.enabled=true -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true "-Dmanagement.endpoints.jmx.exposure.include=*" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2024.1.4\lib\idea_rt.jar=55350:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2024.1.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stdout.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.stderr.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\Saif\spring-security-registration\target\classes;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-web\3.1.0\spring-boot-starter-web-3.1.0.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter\3.1.0\spring-boot-starter-3.1.0.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot\3.1.0\spring-boot-3.1.0.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-autoconfigure\3.1.0\spring-boot-autoconfigure-3.1.0.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-logging\3.1.0\spring-boot-starter-logging-3.1.0.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-classic\1.4.7\logback-classic-1.4.7.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-to-slf4j\2.20.0\log4j-to-slf4j-2.20.0.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\apache\logging\log4j\log4j-api\2.20.0\log4j-api-2.20.0.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\jul-to-slf4j\2.0.7\jul-to-slf4j-2.0.7.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\jakarta\annotation\jakarta.annotation-api\2.1.1\jakarta.annotation-api-2.1.1.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-json\3.1.0\spring-boot-starter-json-3.1.0.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jdk8\2.15.0\jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.15.0.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.15.0\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.15.0.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\module\jackson-module-parameter-names\2.15.0\jackson-module-parameter-names-2.15.0.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-tomcat\3.1.0\spring-boot-starter-tomcat-3.1.0.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-core\10.1.8\tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-websocket\10.1.8\tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.8.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-web\6.0.9\spring-web-6.0.9.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-beans\6.0.9\spring-beans-6.0.9.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\io\micrometer\micrometer-observation\1.11.0\micrometer-observation-1.11.0.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\io\micrometer\micrometer-commons\1.11.0\micrometer-commons-1.11.0.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-webmvc\6.0.9\spring-webmvc-6.0.9.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context\6.0.9\spring-context-6.0.9.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-expression\6.0.9\spring-expression-6.0.9.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-mail\3.1.0\spring-boot-starter-mail-3.1.0.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-context-support\6.0.9\spring-context-support-6.0.9.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\angus\jakarta.mail\1.1.0\jakarta.mail-1.1.0.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\jakarta\activation\jakarta.activation-api\2.1.2\jakarta.activation-api-2.1.2.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\angus\angus-activation\2.0.0\angus-activation-2.0.0.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf\3.1.0\spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf-3.1.0.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\thymeleaf\thymeleaf-spring6\3.1.1.RELEASE\thymeleaf-spring6-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-validation\3.1.0\spring-boot-starter-validation-3.1.0.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\apache\tomcat\embed\tomcat-embed-el\10.1.8\tomcat-embed-el-10.1.8.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\validator\hibernate-validator\8.0.0.Final\hibernate-validator-8.0.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\jakarta\validation\jakarta.validation-api\3.0.2\jakarta.validation-api-3.0.2.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\jboss\logging\jboss-logging\3.5.0.Final\jboss-logging-3.5.0.Final.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\classmate\1.5.1\classmate-1.5.1.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\jboss\aerogear\aerogear-otp-java\1.0.0\aerogear-otp-java-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-security\3.1.0\spring-boot-starter-security-3.1.0.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aop\6.0.9\spring-aop-6.0.9.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-config\6.1.0\spring-security-config-6.1.0.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-core\6.1.0\spring-security-core-6.1.0.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-crypto\6.1.0\spring-security-crypto-6.1.0.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\springframework\security\spring-security-web\6.1.0\spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\thymeleaf\extras\thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6\3.1.1.RELEASE\thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\slf4j\slf4j-api\2.0.7\slf4j-api-2.0.7.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\javax\servlet\javax.servlet-api\4.0.1\javax.servlet-api-4.0.1.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\javax\servlet\jstl\1.2\jstl-1.2.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\javax\el\el-api\2.2\el-api-2.2.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\passay\passay\1.0\passay-1.0.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\cryptacular\cryptacular\1.0\cryptacular-1.0.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\bouncycastle\bcprov-jdk15on\1.50\bcprov-jdk15on-1.50.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa\3.1.0\spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-3.1.0.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-aop\3.1.0\spring-boot-starter-aop-3.1.0.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.9.19\aspectjweaver-1.9.19.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-jdbc\3.1.0\spring-boot-starter-jdbc-3.1.0.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\com\zaxxer\HikariCP\5.0.1\HikariCP-5.0.1.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jdbc\6.0.9\spring-jdbc-6.0.9.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\orm\hibernate-core\6.2.2.Final\hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\jakarta\persistence\jakarta.persistence-api\3.1.0\jakarta.persistence-api-3.1.0.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\jakarta\transaction\jakarta.transaction-api\2.0.1\jakarta.transaction-api-2.0.1.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\common\hibernate-commons-annotations\6.0.6.Final\hibernate-commons-annotations-6.0.6.Final.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\io\smallrye\jandex\3.0.5\jandex-3.0.5.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\net\bytebuddy\byte-buddy\1.14.4\byte-buddy-1.14.4.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-runtime\4.0.2\jaxb-runtime-4.0.2.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\jaxb-core\4.0.2\jaxb-core-4.0.2.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jaxb\txw2\4.0.2\txw2-4.0.2.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\com\sun\istack\istack-commons-runtime\4.1.1\istack-commons-runtime-4.1.1.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\jakarta\inject\jakarta.inject-api\2.0.1\jakarta.inject-api-2.0.1.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\antlr\antlr4-runtime\4.10.1\antlr4-runtime-4.10.1.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-jpa\3.1.0\spring-data-jpa-3.1.0.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\springframework\data\spring-data-commons\3.1.0\spring-data-commons-3.1.0.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-orm\6.0.9\spring-orm-6.0.9.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-tx\6.0.9\spring-tx-6.0.9.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-aspects\6.0.9\spring-aspects-6.0.9.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\com\mysql\mysql-connector-j\8.0.32\mysql-connector-j-8.0.32.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\com\h2database\h2\2.1.214\h2-2.1.214.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\32.0.0-jre\guava-32.0.0-jre.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\failureaccess\1.0.1\failureaccess-1.0.1.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\listenablefuture\9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava\listenablefuture-9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\com\google\code\findbugs\jsr305\3.0.2\jsr305-3.0.2.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\checkerframework\checker-qual\3.33.0\checker-qual-3.33.0.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\com\google\errorprone\error_prone_annotations\2.18.0\error_prone_annotations-2.18.0.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\com\google\j2objc\j2objc-annotations\2.8\j2objc-annotations-2.8.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\com\github\ua-parser\uap-java\1.4.0\uap-java-1.4.0.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\yaml\snakeyaml\1.33\snakeyaml-1.33.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-collections4\4.1\commons-collections4-4.1.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\com\maxmind\geoip2\geoip2\2.15.0\geoip2-2.15.0.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\com\maxmind\db\maxmind-db\2.0.0\maxmind-db-2.0.0.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpclient\4.5.13\httpclient-4.5.13.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\apache\httpcomponents\httpcore\4.4.16\httpcore-4.4.16.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.2\commons-logging-1.2.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\commons-codec\commons-codec\1.15\commons-codec-1.15.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.15.0\jackson-databind-2.15.0.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.15.0\jackson-core-2.15.0.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.15.0\jackson-annotations-2.15.0.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\apache\groovy\groovy\4.0.12\groovy-4.0.12.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\jakarta\xml\bind\jakarta.xml.bind-api\4.0.0\jakarta.xml.bind-api-4.0.0.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-core\6.0.9\spring-core-6.0.9.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-jcl\6.0.9\spring-jcl-6.0.9.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\net\logstash\logback\logstash-logback-encoder\4.8\logstash-logback-encoder-4.8.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\ch\qos\logback\logback-core\1.4.7\logback-core-1.4.7.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-configuration-processor\3.1.0\spring-boot-configuration-processor-3.1.0.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\nz\net\ultraq\thymeleaf\thymeleaf-layout-dialect\3.2.1\thymeleaf-layout-dialect-3.2.1.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\nz\net\ultraq\groovy\groovy-extensions\2.1.0\groovy-extensions-2.1.0.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\nz\net\ultraq\thymeleaf\thymeleaf-expression-processor\3.1.1\thymeleaf-expression-processor-3.1.1.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\thymeleaf\thymeleaf\3.1.1.RELEASE\thymeleaf-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\ognl\ognl\3.3.4\ognl-3.3.4.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\javassist\javassist\3.29.0-GA\javassist-3.29.0-GA.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\attoparser\attoparser\2.0.6.RELEASE\attoparser-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar;C:\Users\Saif\.m2\repository\org\unbescape\unbescape\1.1.6.RELEASE\unbescape-1.1.6.RELEASE.jar com.baeldung.Application

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.1.0)

web - 2024-07-12 16:52:23,564 [background-preinit] INFO  o.h.v.i.u.Version - HV000001: Hibernate Validator 8.0.0.Final
web - 2024-07-12 16:52:23,702 [main] INFO  c.b.Application - Starting Application using Java 22.0.1 with PID 7648 (C:\Users\Saif\spring-security-registration\target\classes started by Saif in C:\Users\Saif\spring-security-registration)
web - 2024-07-12 16:52:23,703 [main] DEBUG c.b.Application - Running with Spring Boot v3.1.0, Spring v6.0.9
web - 2024-07-12 16:52:23,704 [main] INFO  c.b.Application - The following 1 profile is active: "dev"
web - 2024-07-12 16:52:27,061 [main] INFO  o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol - Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
web - 2024-07-12 16:52:27,062 [main] INFO  o.a.c.c.StandardService - Starting service [Tomcat]
web - 2024-07-12 16:52:27,063 [main] INFO  o.a.c.c.StandardEngine - Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.8]
web - 2024-07-12 16:52:27,238 [main] INFO  o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/] - Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
web - 2024-07-12 16:52:27,484 [main] INFO  o.h.j.i.u.LogHelper - HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
web - 2024-07-12 16:52:27,590 [main] INFO  o.h.Version - HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.2.2.Final
web - 2024-07-12 16:52:27,594 [main] INFO  o.h.c.Environment - HHH000406: Using bytecode reflection optimizer
web - 2024-07-12 16:52:27,860 [main] INFO  o.h.b.i.BytecodeProviderInitiator - HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : bytebuddy
web - 2024-07-12 16:52:28,135 [main] INFO  c.z.h.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Starting...
web - 2024-07-12 16:52:28,467 [main] INFO  c.z.h.p.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Added connection conn0: url=jdbc:h2:mem:registration_02 user=SA
web - 2024-07-12 16:52:28,470 [main] INFO  c.z.h.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
web - 2024-07-12 16:52:28,536 [main] INFO  o.h.o.dialect - HHH035001: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect, version: 2.1.214
web - 2024-07-12 16:52:29,053 [main] INFO  o.h.b.i.BytecodeProviderInitiator - HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : bytebuddy
web - 2024-07-12 16:52:30,521 [main] INFO  o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator - HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
web - 2024-07-12 16:52:32,667 [main] WARN  o.s.b.a.o.j.JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration - spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
web - 2024-07-12 16:52:33,220 [main] WARN  o.s.s.c.a.w.b.WebSecurity - You are asking Spring Security to ignore Ant [pattern='/resources/**', /h2/**]. This is not recommended -- please use permitAll via HttpSecurity#authorizeHttpRequests instead.
web - 2024-07-12 16:52:33,616 [main] INFO  o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol - Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
web - 2024-07-12 16:52:34,281 [main] INFO  c.b.Application - Started Application in 11.401 seconds (process running for 13.346)
web - 2024-07-12 16:52:43,885 [http-nio-8081-exec-2] INFO  o.a.c.h.Http11Processor - Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
j.l.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name [0x160x030x010x060xb20x010x000x060xae0x030x030x99{0x16mc0xfa0x84dp0xd60xeb!0x0c0x0d0xfdCu0x920xfc- ]. HTTP method names must be tokens
    at o.a.c.h.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:407)
    at o.a.c.h.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:263)
    at o.a.c.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at o.a.c.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894)
    at o.a.t.u.n.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741)
    ... 5 frames truncated
web - 2024-07-12 16:52:43,885 [http-nio-8081-exec-1] INFO  o.a.c.h.Http11Processor - Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
j.l.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name [0x160x030x010x060xd20x010x000x060xce0x030x03D0xbbON0x8b0x1f0xcc0xc80xb7swSVh0xb3a0xa90x0c0xf10xf85q0xce0xed0xc1X)0x030x160xbd0xfeF ]. HTTP method names must be tokens
    at o.a.c.h.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:407)
    at o.a.c.h.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:263)
    at o.a.c.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at o.a.c.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894)
    at o.a.t.u.n.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741)
    ... 5 frames truncated
web - 2024-07-12 16:53:51,641 [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] INFO  c.z.h.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
web - 2024-07-12 16:53:51,643 [SpringApplicationShutdownHook] INFO  c.z.h.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

Process finished with exit code 130

Thanks!

I pulled a repo
Tried to take a build
Getting Error


This question is similar to: When Spring Boot starts up, it throws the "method names must be tokens" exception. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
